# Which algorithm is fastest in walking in binary tree to any given node at a any level of tree

Tags: algorithm, networking, tree

for example:-there are computers connected in a binary tree structure. There are 20 rooms consider each room as a level in the binary tree starting from room 0 (level 0) in which the main computer is placed and all its children nodes (computers) are in room 1 (level 1) and so on. Each computer is numbered according to its place in the room  like computer1 , computer 2, computer3 and computer4 (maximum number of computers in room2 is equals to the 2 raised to the power 2)in room 1 (level 1).Now starting from the root if I want to get to the computer756 in room 12 what is the fastest algorithm or method.

[image]

considering the above image as an example level 4 has total 16 nodes (1 to 16 say)that is 2 raised to the power 4. If the tree is huge (say tree with 50 levels) which is the fastest algorithm to access the node numbered 1,099,511,628,800 at level 50

Comment: What do you mean by "walking randomly to a given node"? If you know the target node, there is only one path to it from the root, so how could it be random?

Comment: I don't find it easy to understand the question. Can you rephrase it in terms of standard graph or tree language?

Comment: routing protocols use deterministic algorithms to determine the shortest path, not random walks.

Comment: Also a binary tree only has two children, so your description is quite confusing.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut is it understandable now I have added an image after your comments

Comment: @UDB it is still not clear from where you want to reach what computer? From the root to the "1,099,511,628,800"-th node, you have to do a BFS or DFS.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, given `N` and `L` you want to find a path from the root to the `N`th node in the `L`th level. I'll assume that the nodes in each level are numbered left-to-right, and that `N` and `L` are zero-based.

This is simple if you use the binary representation of `N`: Represent `N` as a binary number of `L` bits. Now go through these bits from most significant to least significant. A 0 means that you need to go to the left child, and a 1 means that you need to go the the right child.

For example, to find node #3 in level #3: The node number in binary is `011`. So from the root, you go left, right, right.